# Shell security with hash

Tags: c, security, shell

**For educational purposes** I'm implementing a simple remote shell program, and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to make it somewhat secure. The first idea I had was to just require a password. If the client sends the password, it runs, if not, it quits. Then, I applied a simple hash function to the password, but I don't think this really makes it any more secure. In either case, if the packets are intercepted, an attacker could just extract the password or the hashed password. <s>What can I do to make this more secure</s> Is there a way to use password/hashing that is safe from basic packet interception? I know that ssh uses public/private keys to encrypt and decrypt, but that is more advanced than I need.

Comment: If this is for your own edification, power to you, but why are you insisting on implementing a less-secure version of a secure service?

Comment: Making your own SSH is even more advanced than you need.

Comment: @Hassan This is for educational purposes. I'm trying to make tcp sockets work, and understand network security.

Comment: @roviuser Oh, my mistake. Well, good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a challenge/response with digests? Say the server knows the password is `"blah"`.

The client connects, and authenticates:

- Client: Let me in!
- Server: I give you the challenge `"12345"`, a number I generated just now!

  *Server remembers that they gave the client `"12345"`.*
- *Client wants to authenticate with `"blah"`, so they add it to the end of the server's challenge, and then calculates the SHA-1 of the result `"12345blah"`.*

  Client: My response is `"6910972fb3148a63df7fda34bd6fccf3013d8d93"`!
- *Server knows the password is `"blah"`, and issued the challenge `"12345"` to this client—hence it calculates the SHA-1 of `"12345blah"`, and produces `"6910972fb3148a63df7fda34bd6fccf3013d8d93"`.  This matches the client's response so …*

  Server: Access granted!

Important notes:

- The server *MUST* be the one to choose the challenge. If the client gets to pick, then an attacker could just intercept one authentication attempt, and repeat the same challenge and response as that valid user.

  The fact that the server picks a *different challenge every time* means an attacker can't replay authentication. This means the server needs to store the challenge against the client's connection or session somehow, since you'll need it when they respond.
- You may want to use something stronger than SHA-1 (it's a little broken IIRC). You may also want to do something other than just appending the password to the challenge, as the security properties depend on the underlying digest function.
- I demonstrate this with a password `"blah"`, but the nice thing is now, you can replace `"blah"` with the hash of `"blah"`. The server never needs to store more than the hash, and then the client just hashes their password first before combining with the challenge and calculating the digest.

Comment: So because the client hashes the password and the unique challenge together, the "attacker" can't extract the password, right?

Comment: Right! But the differentiating point is that the challenge is never repeated. Even if you just sent a hashed password per your question, the password can still never be recovered—the problem is that the hashed password is just as valuable. In this case, because the hash depends on the challenge, there's no reuse value for what's actually sent across the wire.

Comment: This breaks apart if the server ever repeats a challenge—if we intercept the response for challenge *A*, and then we ourselves receive challenge *A*, we can reuse that response. But we can do things like include the current time, etc. in the challenge, to reduce the likelihood of that.

Comment: The security really depends on the hash function, though: if there's some way of breaking it, or of deriving useful information about the hash input, from the output, or from many outputs (for which the input is partially known; a hacker knows the challenge in every case), then it could be weakened. Of course, an [ideal hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) doesn't leak any of this …

Comment: @Len In what way is SHA-1 broken?

Comment: This discussion, while valuable, is moot if the channel was just properly encrypted; and the channel should be encrypted anyway, as a user thinking "I'm on a secure channel" will think nothing of typing in passwords for a variety of other services (kerberized telnet had this very issue), which may be more valuable to the attacker than the shell password itself.

Comment: @tbert: True. In this discussion, then, "properly encrypted" should integrity protection, i.e. signing, such that an attacker doesn't just insert packets with possibly random/possibly dangerous intent.

Comment: @glglgl: [SHA-1 Broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html), February 2005. See the follow-up, [Cryptanalysis of SHA-1](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html). SHA-1 should and can be avoided in new work. Why not SHA-512?

Comment: Your last point - the server not knowing the password - isn't as simple as you describe. The benefit would be that if I have the same password on two servers, neither can impersonate me on the other (because they don't know my password). But with your suggestion, knowing the hash is just as good.

Comment: @Len I get the impression that this is going to end up being a bad copy of most of the terminal featureset of ssh, eventually

Comment: @tbert: agreed, but I don't think that that's an issue here. OP's just trying to have fun and learn here.

Comment: @ugoren: a good point. In that case, a client may wish to send a salted hash, and would need to receive the salt along with the challenge. I'm sure there are better ways, but I can't think of them off the top of my head.